# Running hundreds of WP in multisite

Tags: multisite

We are starting to rack up the number of WP websites and we're looking to have a bit more control over all of them, would multi site be the correct way to go?

All the sites are running on different domains, different versions of WP and different plugins (with different versions of those). I don't want to blanket update all of the versions because I don't want to risk things breaking.

So with that in mind would the only benefit be that I would have a super admin access and be able to switch between the sites quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, if you cant upgrade to 3.0=> then you could use something like http://managewp.com/ that adds the functions to control multiply sites from "one dashboard".

Im running a big multisite for all my min-clients with separate domains etc. And its really nice to have that control of all the sites.

Comment: Are there any other benefits apart from them all being in one dashboard? Yep - all sites are version 3.0+.

Comment: Update WordPress once for all sites in a a WPMS network. Makes keeping up-to-date, and therefore more secure, quick and easy.
Run one daily database backup on the main site, and includes child site tables. Practically effortless with a set-and-forget plugin

Comment: And also in further development you can use a "base" theme and build child-themes on that to get a more crisp environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd have to be running at least 3.0 and it would be the same version on all your blogs, if that's a deal breaker then Multiste isn't for you I'm afraid. Personally I love it though!

Comment: Yep they're all 3.0+. Are there any other benefits that make your life easier with it?

Comment: as others have said makes updates to themes, if there shared across a lot of sites, a lot less painful. I know you said you don't want to update certain sites but it is a good idea to keep them up to date for security, and this is soooo much easier with multisite in place. Also you get to be a 'super admin' rather then just an admin, if that's not reason enough I don't know what is ;-)

Comment: domain mapping isn't to difficult either, so you can have a separate domain for each site, can be handled with a plugin. Simply, just makes everything so much more manageable.